# Bigram Tokenization is not obtained

Tags: r

I am trying to do Bigram Tokenization on csv file. But it is taking a lot of time. I have checked my code with the existing codes in SO. I couldn't find any fault in it. My code is displayed below:

```
library(tm)
library(RWeka)
library(tmcn.word2vec)
library(openNLP)
library(NLP)

data <- read.csv("Train.csv", header=T)

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(data$EventDescription))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,PlainTextDocument)

BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,control=list(tokenize=BigramTokenizer))
```

Can anyone help me in solving this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem here. Are you saying this works but takes a long time? How long does it take? How big is your corpus?

Comment: I have 1236 corpus. But the code isn't working for such a huge data

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading the sources into a `VCorpus` instead of a `Corpus`. See:

[Document-term matrix in R - bigram tokenizer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604439/document-term-matrix-in-r-bigram-tokenizer-not-working) and [Creating N-Grams with tm & RWeka - works with VCorpus but not Corpus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757183/creating-n-grams-with-tm-rweka-works-with-vcorpus-but-not-corpus)