# Document-term matrix in R - bigram tokenizer not working

Tags: r, tokenize, tm, n-gram, rweka

I am trying to make 2 document-term matrices for a corpus, one with unigrams and one with bigrams. However, the bigram matrix is currently just identical to the unigram matrix, and I'm not sure why.

The code:

```
docs<-Corpus(DirSource("data", recursive=TRUE))

# Get the document term matrices
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
dtm_unigram <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs, control = list(tokenize="words", 
    removePunctuation = TRUE, 
    stopwords = stopwords("english"), 
    stemming = TRUE))
dtm_bigram <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer,
    removePunctuation = TRUE,
    stopwords = stopwords("english"),
    stemming = TRUE))

inspect(dtm_unigram)
inspect(dtm_bigram)
```

I also tried using ngram(x, n=2) from the ngram package as the tokenizer, but that doesn't work either. How do I fix the bigram tokenization?

Comment: I am also having this issue so if you found the answer please let me know.

Comment: Bit late on the reply, sorry - but I got this working by using VCorpus instead of Corpus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tokenizer option doesn't seem to work with Corpus (SimpleCorpus). Using VCorpus instead cleared up the problem.

Comment: Why `VCorpus` over `Corpus`? There is another related SO problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757183/creating-n-grams-with-tm-rweka-works-with-vcorpus-but-not-corpus) but there doesn't seem to be satisfying explanation.