# R: Obtaining Single Term Frequencies instead of Bigrams

Tags: r, tm, rweka

Here is the code I use to create bi-grams with frequency list:

```
library(tm)
library(RWeka)
#data <- myData[,2]


tdm.generate <- function(string, ng){

  # tutorial on rweka - http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html

  corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(string)) # create corpus for TM processing
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers) 
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
  # corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
  options(mc.cores=1) # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703553/bigrams-instead-of-single-words-in-termdocument-matrix-using-r-and-rweka/20251039#20251039
  BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = ng, max = ng)) # create n-grams
  tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer)) # create tdm from n-grams
  tdm
}



source("GenerateTDM.R") # generatetdm function in appendix
tdm <- tdm.generate("The book The book The greatest The book",2)

tdm.matrix <- as.matrix(tdm)
topwords <- rowSums(tdm.matrix)
topwords <- as.numeric(topwords)
hist(topwords, breaks = 10)


tdm.matrix <- as.matrix(tdm)
topwords <- rowSums(tdm.matrix)
head(sort(topwords, decreasing = TRUE))
```

The result for the above code is:

```
the     book greatest 
4        3        1
```

Instead, I'm looking for the result where bi-grams are shown like:

```
"the book" "book the"
  3          2
```

What needs to be changed in the above code to get the output as above?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use VCorpus instead of Corpus, I was having the same issue you could check more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604439/document-term-matrix-in-r-bigram-tokenizer-not-working?rq=1)